# Return array from tuple

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, tuples, iteration

I am trying to return two arrays from 1 tuple at once.

I have a (large) iteration

```
def iteration_newton(...., ....,)
```

with at the end of the iteration

```
return x_save, V
```

Where `x_save` is a matrix of `28x1000` and `V` is an array of `1x1000`.

Now what I did is:

```
Results = iteration_newton(...., ....,)[0]
```

to get the values `x_save` as an array, and:

```
V = iteration_newton(...., ....,)[1]
```

to get the values `V` as an array.

Though the problem here is that the iteration runs two times for this and it costs the program a lot of time.

Is there a possibility to not let is iterate twice and collect the values at once?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of unpacking assignment:

```
Results, V = iteration_newton(...., ....,)
```

which is somehow similar to:

```
iteration = iteration_newton(...., ....,)  #  calculate it once and store it for later use
Results = iteration[0]
V = iteration[1]
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I needed and surprisingly easy!

Comment: Results, V = iteration_newton(...., ....)     this will also work.No need to put comma at the end